# Групировка inline кнопок в telegram bot на PHP

Tags: php, telegram-bot

Подтолкните в правильном направлении

```
$keyboard_pro = [[
    ['text' => 'Что такое PRO?',      'callback_data' => 'about_pro'],
    ['text' => 'Приобрести PRO',      'callback_data' => 'pro'],
    ['text' => 'Что такое Подписка?', 'callback_data' => 'about_subscribe'],
    ['text' => 'Приобрести Подписку', 'callback_data' => 'subscribe']
]];
$keyboard_PRO_n_SUBSCRIBE = json_encode(['inline_keyboard' => $keyboard_pro]);
```

Бот выводит сообщение и под ним четыре кнопки, все бы ничего, да только кнопки выстраиваются в одну линию и текст не читается. Мне бы между кнопками аналог `<br>`, только на php)

в результате хочу получить две строки с кнопками по две шт в каждой строке

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй так

```
$keyboard_pro = [
[
  ['text' => 'Что такое PRO?',      'callback_data' => 'about_pro'],
  ['text' => 'Приобрести PRO',      'callback_data' => 'pro']
],
[
  ['text' => 'Что такое Подписка?', 'callback_data' => 'about_subscribe'],
  ['text' => 'Приобрести Подписку', 'callback_data' => 'subscribe']
]
];
```

Comment: Спасибо! Я правил Ваш ответ, что бы он точно соответствовал запрошенному решению!))

Comment: Типо по две кнопки на строчку*

Comment: Ваш ответ делает один столбик из четырех кнопок, а я хотел два столбика (ну или строки) по две кнопки))

Comment: @4kilograms я похоже не дочитал вопрос